# What is the most efficient way to convert a string to a char array/ value that a char pointer can point to

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, memcpy

If I have a string:

```
std::string Pooptacular = "Pooptacular"
```

and I want to convert it to a char array, I have some options
one being:

```
char* poopCArr = Pooptacular.c_str();
```

or I can do something with memcpy or strcpy and such.

What I want to know is, which of these methods is the fastest
or most efficient.  In other words, which method should I use if
I were to do this hundreds of thousands of times in one program run?

Comment: Depends on the usage. `.c_str()` does not copy anything, just returns `const char*` to the memory, used in the `std::string`. Will you modify it? Also, `const char* poorCArr` is not `char` array.

Comment: Have you tried to measure anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a read-only pointer to the data, use `c_str`.  It doesn't convert anything.  It just gives you access to the buffer `string` has already allocated.  Of course, you have to copy it to a new buffer if you want to change it, and if you do, don't expect your changes to be reflected in your original `string` object.

Comment: Just what I needed. Muchas gracias

Comment: One more thing about this answer, when you ask to the pointer using `string::c_str` you're getting a pointer to **internal string data**, this breaks the encapsulation principle, it could be troublesome even if you rely on this pointer to perform read-only operations: what would happen if the `std::string` instance owner of the `const char *` is deleted?. IMHO is better to work with the `std::string` object instead of its `const char *` internal pointers btw: @kjh don't forget to mark the answer as accepted ;)